# Is there a way to limit Apache Airflow catchup interval

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

In Apache Airflow, if we set a DAG's catchup to be `True`, it will schedule all the runs that were not progressed since the `start_date`. So in case I turn off a DAG and then turn it on 1 year later, it will schedule tons of runs. And I want to avoid this. So is there any way to set a specific interval for catchup? For example, only catchup the runs that are within 1 month in the past from the current time.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you try `end_date` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAGs have `start_date` but they also have optional parameter of `end_date`.

You should set `end_date` for your DAG.

```
DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    ...,
    catchup=True,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    end_date=datetime(2022, 2, 1),
)
```